# Kernel of a morphism of affine varieties is closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $X, Y$ be affine varieties and  $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ a morphism. 
Could someone please explain me why $ker \phi$ is closed?

By definition $\phi$ is continuous and satisfies for all $V \subseteq Y$ open, for all $f \in O_Y(V)$ we have 
$$
f \circ \phi \in O_X(\phi^{-1}(V)). 
$$
I don't see how from this we can see that $ker \phi$ is a closed set in $X$... Thank you.

Edit. I like to add that $X$ and $Y$ are affine algerbaic groups.

Comment: The preimage of a closed set is closed and here the kernel is the preimage of the closed set $\{0\}$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by kernel of a morphism of varieties. If these varieties are group varieties or something, then Wuestenfux has given you your answer.

Comment: In general $\ker\phi$ has not sense...

Comment: @Wuestenfux Thank you for this!